# TortoiseGit can't find git.exe

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I've performed a clean install for `TortoiseGit` and the latest `Git for Windows` on my `Windows 10` OS, but there seems to be a problem with Tortoise claiming that it can't find Git's executable.

The path to the Git executable set within Tortoise is correct and in addition I've already added the corresponding entry to the PATH environment variable.

Every time I try to create a repo or if I go under settings, the following message pops up:

> git.exe not correctly set up (/usr/bin/bash: /bin/git.exe: No such file or directory)
>
> Check TortoiseGit settings and consult help for "Git.exe Path".

---

Summary:

- Windows 10 (x64)
- TortoiseGit (x64 / v2.1.0.0)
- Git (x64 / v2.9.0)

Installation-Paths:

- Tortoise: "A:\Programs\TortoiseGit"
- Git: "A:\Programs\Git\bin"

Added entries for PATH-Variable:

- "A:\Programs\Git\bin"
- "A:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin"

Comment: May I ask why you enabled those?

Comment: CygwinHack was enabled by default, the same goes for Msys which was disabled. I guess this has something to do with remaining registry entries for my previously installed cygwin installation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Both hacks are not enabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Git for Windows don't enable Cygwin or Msys hacks!

These are only for the git.exe version shipped with the cygwin or msys2 (not Git for Windows!) package.

Comment: I got the same issue and Cygwin or Msys hacks are disabled. this is not a fresh install. Any Idea?

Comment: @Sahan check that your git.exe file in C:\Progrma Files\Git\bin does not set to run as administrator (see file properties)